# Timer.stop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

I have this code inside a button to stop a timer

```
Private Sub btnStopICMP_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStopICMP.Click
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

But after 5 seconds the timer stops.
This means that after pressing the STOP TIMER button, the timer for 5 seconds continues to do its thing.
Any advice to make it stop at the moment of pressing the STOP button?

This is the code that goes in the timer, it changes color every second.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If time = 1 Then
            label1.Color = Color.Gold
        ElseIf time = 2 Then
            label1.Color = Color.White
            time = 0
        End If
        time = time + 1
End Sub
```

I have tried

```
Private Sub btnStopICMP_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStopICMP.Click
  Timer1.Enabled = False    
  Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

Without any result.

Comment: More detailed information is needed, such as what code is present in the `Timer1_Tick` event and whether it takes a long time to execute. `Timer1.Stop()` and `Timer1.Enabled = False` are essentially the same. They both prevent _Timer1_ from executing the code in the `Timer1_Tick` event during the next **Interval**. So, I guess you want the code that is running in `Timer1_Tick` to stop immediately, is that correct?

Comment: @Songpl It is correct, that the code that is in timer_tick stops immediately. But it stops 5 seconds after passing timer1.stop() to it.

Comment: Interval value is 1000  or 5000? time? Do you need the label's color to alternate between gold and white every second? And should the alternating stop either when a certain count is reached or when a button is clicked?

Comment: @Songpl The interval is 1000 and the color change must stop when the button is pressed, that is, if the button is not pressed, the color change enters an infinite loop.

Comment: @Songpl Unfortunately when the button to stop the timer is pressed, the color change still goes on for 5 seconds, then it stops.

Comment: If what you describe is really happening then your system is broken and we can't help you. I suggest that you actually use the debugger and make sure that you're clear about what's actually happening. Make sure that the `Click` event handler of your `Button` is executed at the time you click it. Also, look at the `Enabled` property of the `Timer` inside its `Tick` event handler to see whether it is actually disabled or not. If the handler is executed when the `Timer` is disabled then that suggest that the events were actually raised before you stopped the `Timer` but handled after.

Comment: Your code to change the `Label` colour is overly complex. Seems like you could just use `label1.Color = If(label1.Color = Color.Gold, Color.White, Color.Gold)`. Basically just change the colour to whatever it isn't currently.

Comment: @jmcilhinney :(

Comment: @TomWelling 1) I suggest that you make a new project with just the form and the buttons that are needed to operate the timer. Does it work properly? 2) If you used Application.DoEvents() anywhere, that could be messing everything up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different approach. Define a Boolean variable to control the color alternation, and as for that Timer, just keep it running continuously.

```vb
Dim IsRunning As Boolean = False

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If Not IsRunning Then Exit Sub

    Label1.BackColor = IIf(Label1.BackColor = Color.Gold, Color.White, Color.Gold)

End Sub

Private Sub btnICMP_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnICMP.Click
    IsRunning = Not IsRunning
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

Comment: Since the introduction of the `If` operator in VB 2008, you should not be using the `IIf` function. It was dodgy even before that but now it has no value at all. The `If` operator has multiple advantages, not least of which is that it will work with `Option Strict On`, where your code would require `Option Strict Off` to compile, which is a very bad thing.

Comment: I'm not sure that this really solves anything because, if this code works, the original code should work too. I suspect that there is something else going on here that this will not fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Reflection.Emit
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.TaskbarClock

Public Class Form1
    Dim time As Integer
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If Time = 1 Then
            Label1.BackColor = Color.Gold
        ElseIf Time = 2 Then
            Label1.BackColor = Color.White
            time = 0
        End If
        time = time + 1

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Stop()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: In Theory, the Timer should stop instantly to press the button, but stop 5 seconds later, and during those 5 seconds the label1 continues to change color.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you fix this, Label1.Color = .  This does,

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static time As Integer = 1
    If time = 1 Then
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Gold '<<<<<
    ElseIf time = 2 Then
        Label1.BackColor = Color.White '<<<<<
        time = 0
    End If
    time = time + 1
End Sub

Private Sub btnStopICMP_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStopICMP.Click
    ' either works
    'Timer1.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

Comment: The code works, the problem is that the Timer does not stop at the time of pressing the button, takes its time 5 seconds approx. and during that time the label1 continues to change color.